# AngularJS Share Data Between Controllers Using Service And Watch For Updates

Tags: angularjs

Simple task here, but not sure about the mistake.

My service:

```
app.factory('Progress', function () {

    var data = {
        progressPercentageLoaded: 0
    };

    return {
        getProgress: function () {
            return data.progressPercentageLoaded;
        },
        setProgress: function (progress) {
            data.progressPercentageLoaded = progress;
        }
    };
});
```

I have one controller that is uploading a file, this one sets the progress value.

```
//in my controller
$scope.progressPercentageLoaded = {progress:0};
//a few lines down
function (evt) {
console.log(evt);
$scope.progressPercentageLoaded.progress = evt.loaded;
Progress.setProgress($scope.progressPercentageLoaded.progress);
```

My second controller should simply watch the service for changes and update the view, but it stays stuck at zero even though I confirm the upload is happening and that `evt.loaded` is changing.

```
$scope.progress = 0;
$scope.$watch(function () { return Progress.getProgress(); }, function (newValue, oldValue) {
        if (newValue !== oldValue) {
            $scope.progress = Math.min(100, parseInt(100 * newValue / $scope.size));
            if($scope.progress == 100)
            {
                $scope.progressModalInstance.close();
                window.location.reload();
            }
        }
    });
```

That is, `$scope.progress` in second controller should update with the value of `evt.loaded` in the first controller, but it doesn't.

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

***EDIT:*** I even added the third `watch` parameter as `true` but that didn't help either.

***EDIT 2 :*** The code above actually works to the best of my knowledge, I believe something else was causing a problem as when I reverted the code to the above after editing it due to the answers, it suddenly worked like it should. Sorry about this.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console? Do these controllers inherit from each other? I created a simple example with 2 controllers and I see the watcher executing. But instead of uploading a file, I called `setProgress` every 2 seconds: `var p = 0; setInterval(function() { $scope.$apply(function() { Progress.setProgress(++p); }); }, 2000);` Does this work for you?

Comment: @FrankModica The code above actually works, I don't know why it wasn't working before but I just reverted it back to the above and it functions fine. I saw the upload event being recorded but no change in the upload percent, maybe the upload was so big that it didn't change even as more of it was being uploaded? I'm not sure but I tried with a few small files just now and the view was updated appropriately without any changes to the above code, sorry for wasting your time! :(

Comment: No problem, glad it's working :)

Answer (score 1):

using $rootScope.$broadcast will work better for this

app.factory('Progress', function ($rootScope) {

```
var data = {
    progressPercentageLoaded: 0
};

    return {
        getProgress: function () {
            $rootScope.$broadcast('Event');
            return data.progressPercentageLoaded;
        },
        setProgress: function (progress) {
            data.progressPercentageLoaded = progress;
        }
    };
});
```

In your second controller instead of using watch
something like

```
$rootScope.$on('Event', function(){
    //your logic here
})
```

Comment: I'd prefer to stick with `watch` if possible.

Answer (score 1):

You are losing the reference because you are watching the `Int` value that you are updating every time, hence you are changing the reference. You have to watch the whole object `progressPercentageLoaded`.

You have to pass true as the last parameter of the `$watch` function so that the equality check is `angular.equals`. Otherwise, only reference equality is checked.

Comment: I'm sorry, I understand what you are saying but not where in the code to make this change... I only watch `Progress.getProgress();` and if I just return the object there instead of `data.progressPercentageLoaded;` I still have the same problem!

Comment: I have `true` as the last parameter and it still doesn't work.

Comment: But isn't the int value being updated on the same object each time? And returned from that same object? I don't think the reference is the problem.

Comment: try attaching the service into your controller's scope `$scope.progress = Progress.getProgress();` and then watch `$scope.progress`

Comment: That doesn't work either... if I `console.log()` the old and new Value from the watch, I always just get `0,0` once and it never updates again.

Comment: Are you sure that setProgress is being called?

Comment: Yes I am, also I just reverted the code to what it was when I started the question, no `$apply`, no watching the whole object and it worked. I'm not sure why it wasn't working before but it was functioning as initially presented. Sorry to waste your time.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure, but Angular may not be aware of the file upload event. Try calling `$apply`:

```
$scope.$apply(function() {
   Progress.setProgress($scope.progressPercentageLoaded.progress);
});
```

Comment: I had thought this was the case and tried it previously, and just now, and it didn't solve the problem. :(